# Runnable jar asking for user input on console on double click

Tags: java, windows, jar

I have a simple program which takes `userName` as input and outputs `Hello userName`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String userName = null;
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    userName = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println("Hello " + userName);
}
```

I export this from eclipse as a `Runnable Jar` called `sayHello.jar`

When I open a command prompt in windows and do `java -jar sayHello.jar` it works as expected.

However, when I double click the jar, nothing happens.

I even did a right click on the jar and did `open with` and selected `java.exe` but same result - nothing happens.

Is it possible for the jar to behave like I want? That is, I double click the jar, it opens the window to get my input, then says hello and waits for my enter to terminate?

Comment: right click, open with `javaw.exe`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat `javaw.exe` will start in console-less mode, which I don't think the OP wants, I think they want the "dos box" to present

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: did that.. same result.. nothing happens